# Some content is not displaying on one of my Drupal 7 pages

Tags: nodes, theming

I inherited a development theme and I am a Drupal newbie. I don't seem to be able to print out any new fields that I add to my content types. I put this code in node.tpl.php:

```
<?php echo render($content['field_my_text']);?>
```

I have the corresponding name in my content type. Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. The new field was initially set to hidden inside the manage display tab of the "full content" (instead of the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The new field was initially set to hidden inside the manage display tab of the "full content" (instead of the default).